# Hard drive temperature in HP ProLiant DL380 G7

Tags: hdd

Which temperature sensor shows the temperature of the hard drives in the HP ProLiant DL380 G7 server using ILO 3? (the "Temperature" tab shows 30 temperature sensors, but which one is responsible for the token disk?). Is there a transcript of the temperature sensor readings for the HP ProLiant DL380 G7?

Answer (score 0):

There is no iLO ("external") thermal sensor for harddrives, because it wouldn't make sense to measure the temperature on the outside of the device - and iLO would have to know the drive configuration beforehand.

There is a sensor in front of the disk tray ("ambient") and behind it ("stream"), but the reading and interpretation depends on the exact configuration of your server and drives.

But HDDs (and SSDs) do have their own internal sensors. Those are calibrated, very accurate and accessible per-drive. You can read their measurements with S.M.A.R.T. tools like `hddtemp`.

Answer (score 0):

A tool I like to use is CrystalDiskInfo. I find it works on Windows Server 2019, not sure about other OSs tho.

iLO sadly does not have its own drive sensors. The iLO sensors are those that are already on the board.